# Ansible same host unreachable in 2 plays

Tags: ansible

I met with a "surprising" error from Ansible.
I have `hosts: localhost` in 2 consecutive plays.
play1 is ok, in play2 Ansible 2.9 says "localhost" unreachable.
In `host_vars/localhost`, I have `ansible_connection: local`

```
---
############ Play 1 ###############
- name: Test Play 1
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Set facts
      set_fact:
        action_host: localhost

############ Play 2 ###############

- name: Test Play 2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Test Play 2
      shell: |
        echo toto
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Test Play 1] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Set facts] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [Test Play 2] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Test Play 2] ***********************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ cat host_vars/localhost
ansible_connection: local
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Can you tell us anything else about your environment? What does your Ansible inventory look like?

Comment: Since your first play is using `gather_facts: false` and is only containing a `set_fact` tasks, it is actually not making any connection to the host. Only your second play tries to do that. Unless your have (re)defined localhost in your inventory (which is probably a bad idea), you do not need to configure anything (including the connection) as [localhost is implicit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html). From your error message, you are not using the implicit connection since it tries to go through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.
Resolved, finally this was simply because, the playbook was not in the same directory where ansible.cfg was located.
I've copied the file to `~/ansible/.`

```
cd ~/ansible ; ansible-playbook <file>.yaml
```

Then, All well.
If I simply do:

```
cp <file>.yaml  /tmp/.
ansible-playbook /tmp/<file>.yaml
```

Then I get the error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

This is because default connection in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` is `ssh_connection`
Thanks all.